# using the .map() method, how to abbreviate strings to leave the first 3 letters in an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of months and i need to abbreviate down to the first 3 letters of each and have that list placed in a new array.

I'm using the .map method to create the new array.  I've tried the .trim and .slice methods to try to grab the first three letters.  This, however, only succeeded in grabbing the first letter of each string.

```
const months = ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December'];
let abbreviatedMonths = months.map(month => month.slice(0, 1, 2));

console.log(abbreviatedMonths);
>> ['J', 'F', 'M', 'A', 'M', 'J', 'J', 'A', 'S', 'O', 'N', 'D'] to the console
```

I need it to print

```
>> ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `string.substr(start,end)` to easily extract the part of the string you want, then return that in your map. Ex)

```
const months = ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December'];
let abbreviatedMonths = months.map(month => month.substr(0,3));

console.log(abbreviatedMonths) 
>> ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"]
```

You could also do the same thing but with using `string.slice(0,3)` for the same result. The arguments should be the starting index, and the ending index. Looking up the official documentation for use cases like this is very helpful and valuable habit to have as a programmer.

**string.slice()**: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice

**string.substr()**: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substr

Comment: Worked like a charm.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your use of `Array.prototype.map` is correct, but your `slice`-ing needs a tweak. The `slice` method takes two arguments - the index of the first item and the index of the item *after* the last item in the sub-array you want to end up with. We can obtain the first 3 characters with `.slice(0, 3)`.

Answer (score 0):

Recently, I created a simple npm package that offers a unique approach to handling abbreviation of strings within an array. Please, check this

https://www.npmjs.com/package/abbrev-string-array

```
import abbrev from 'abbrev-string-array';

let arr = ['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday']
abbrev (arr) 
// ['M', 'T', 'W', 'Th']

let arr = ['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday']
abbrev (arr, {matchAlikeLen: true}) 
// ['M', 'Tu', 'W', 'Th']

let arr = ['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday']
abbrev (arr, {matchAll: true}) 
// ['Mo', 'Tu', 'We', 'Th']
```

Default option values :

```
   matchAlikeLen = false, 
   matchAll = false, 
   suffix = null, 
   minLen = null, 
   caseSensitive = false
```